# Highcharts Error #15 with wrong data series displayed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

i'm getting weird behavior with my chart.
Basically, it's a dynamically update from mysql db by jsonp callback. it's a 5 series data, one spline type and 4 column type.
First of all, when i load the chart nothing is being shown.
By second, if i select a range with the first or the last of the data series (specifically the today's data or the first day of the series) i get a wrong result with huge values in yaxis and the usual Highcharts #15 error.
i've checked my json using the data series in this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4knAX/2/ and everthing is fine (but the aftersetextremes function is disabled) .
At last, when i select a range of hours, with php output of 15 minutes values, i get only daily values instead.
i've regularly checked the json with jsfiddle and the php code my i cannot get any usable answer from them.
there is my js code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" >
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Telegestione Elektra</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/exporting.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
                            global: {
                                        useUTC: false
                                    }
                            });
        $.getJSON('grafico_nuovo.php?callback=?', function(data) {
                data = [].concat(data, [[Date.UTC(2013, 7, 14, 19, 59), null, null, null, null,null]]);
                val1 = [];val2 = [];val3 = [];val4 = [];val5 = [];
                $.each(data, function (key, value)   {
                    val1.push([value[0], value[1]]);
                    val2.push([value[0], value[2]]);
                    val3.push([value[0], value[3]]);
                    val4.push([value[0], value[4]]);
                    val5.push([value[0], value[5]]);
                                                    });
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            //type: 'spline',
            //zoomType: 'xy'
        },

        navigator: {
            adaptToUpdatedData: false,
            series: {
                data: val1
            }
        },

        scrollbar: {
            liveRedraw: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL history by the minute from 1998 to 2011'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Displaying 1.7 million data points in Highcharts Stock by async server loading'
        },

         rangeSelector : {
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1d'
                }, {
                    type: 'week',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1w'
                },{
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1m'
                },              {
                    type: 'year',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1y'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }],
                inputEnabled: true, // it supports only days
                selected : 1 // day
            },

       xAxis: {         type:"datetime",                        
                                    minRange: 3600 * 1000, // an hour
                                    dateTimeLabelFormats: { minute: '%H:%M', day: '%A. %e/%m' },
                                    labels: {
                                    rotation: 330,
                                    y:20,
                                    staggerLines: 1,
                                                },
                                    events : {
                                        afterSetExtremes : afterSetExtremes
                                            },              
                                    },
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                                        labels: {
                                            format: '{value}°C',
                                            style: {
                                                color: '#89A54E'
                                            }
                                        },
                                        title: {
                                            text: 'Temperature',
                                            style: {
                                                color: '#89A54E'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }, { // Secondary yAxis
                                        title: {
                                            text: 'Consumo',
                                            style: {
                                                color: '#4572A7'
                                            }
                                        },
                                        labels: {
                                            format: '{value} Kw',
                                            style: {
                                                color: '#4572A7'
                                            }
                                        },
                                        opposite: true
                                    }],

        series:[{           name:'Test',
                            type:'spline',
                            tooltip: {
                                            shared:true,
                                                valueSuffix: ' °C',
                                                valueDecimals: 2
                                                    },
                            yAxis: 0,
                            data:val1
                        },
                        {   name:'kwhg',
                            type:'column',
                            yAxis: 1,
                            tooltip: {
                                            shared:true,
                                                valueSuffix: ' Kwh',
                                                valueDecimals: 2
                                                    },
                            data:val2
                        },
                        {   name:'kwhc',
                            yAxis: 1,
                            type:'column',
                            tooltip: {
                                            shared:true,
                                                valueSuffix: ' Kwh',
                                                valueDecimals: 2
                                                    },
                            data:val3
                        },
                        {   name:'kwhi',
                            yAxis: 1,
                            type:'column',
                            tooltip: {
                                            shared:true,
                                                valueSuffix: ' Kwh',
                                                valueDecimals: 2
                                                    },
                            data:val4
                        },
                        {   name:'kwhfm',
                            yAxis: 1,
                            type:'column',
                            tooltip: {
                                            shared:true,
                                                valueSuffix: ' Kwh',
                                                valueDecimals: 2 
                                                    },
                            data:val5
                        },
                        ]
    }, function (chart) {
            chart.showLoading('Loading data from server2...');
            chart.series[0].setData(val1);
            chart.series[1].setData([]);
            chart.series[2].setData([]);
            chart.series[3].setData([]);
            chart.series[4].setData([]);    
            chart.hideLoading();
                        });
    });
});
function afterSetExtremes(e) {

            var currentExtremes = this.getExtremes(),
            range = e.max - e.min,          
            chart = $('#container').highcharts();
            chart.showLoading('Loading data from server3...');  
            //chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(Date.UTC(2014, 0, 2), Date.UTC(2014, 0, 8));
            $.getJSON('grafico_nuovo.php?start='+ Math.round(e.min) +
                        '&end='+ Math.round(e.max) +'&callback=?', function(data)   {
                chart.series[0].setData([]);
                chart.series[1].setData([]);
                chart.series[2].setData([]);
                chart.series[3].setData([]);
                chart.series[4].setData([]);
                $.each(data, function(key,value)    {
                    val1.push([value[0], value[1]]);
                    val2.push([value[0], value[2]]);
                    val3.push([value[0], value[3]]);
                    val4.push([value[0], value[4]]);
                    val5.push([value[0], value[5]]);
                                                    });
                            chart.series[0].setData(val1);
                            chart.series[1].setData(val2);
                            chart.series[2].setData(val3);
                            chart.series[3].setData(val4);
                            chart.series[4].setData(val5);
                            chart.hideLoading();    });
                            };
</script>
        </head>
    <body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 210px; height: 550px; margin: 0 auto; background: url(./img/257.gif);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my php too:

```
<?php
/**
* This file loads content from four different data tables depending on the required time range.
* The stockquotes table containts 1.7 million data points. Since we are loading OHLC data and
* MySQL has no concept of first and last in a data group, we have extracted groups by hours, days
* and months into separate tables. If we were to load a line series with average data, we wouldn't
* have to do this.
*
* @param callback {String} The name of the JSONP callback to pad the JSON within
* @param start {Integer} The starting point in JS time
* @param end {Integer} The ending point in JS time
*/

// get the parameters

$callback = $_GET['callback'];
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', $callback)) {
        die('Invalid callback name');
}

$start = $_GET['start'];
if ($start && !preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $start)) {
        die("Invalid start parameter: $start");
}
if (!$start) $start = (time() - (365 * 24 * 60 * 60)) * 1000;
$end = $_GET['end'];
if ($end && !preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $end)) {
        die("Invalid end parameter: $end");
}
if (!$end) $end = time() * 1000;

// connect to MySQL
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', 'elektra','telegestione');
// set UTC+1 time
mysql_query("SET time_zone = '+01:00'");

// set some utility variables
$range = $end - $start;
//$startTime = gmstrftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', $start / 1000);
$startTime= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(gmstrftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', $start / 1000)));
//$endTime = gmstrftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', $end / 1000);
$endTime= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(gmstrftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', $end / 1000) ));

// find the right table
// two days range loads minute data
if ($range < 3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000) {
        if (!$link)     {
                        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());};  
                        //echo "minute data2" ;
            $result = mysqli_query($link," select 1000*unix_timestamp(q1.time) as time, (q1.kwg) as kwhg, (q1.kwc) as kwhc, (q1.kwi) as kwhi, (q1.kwfm) as kwhfm, (q2.test) as test from 
            (select dataora as time, kwg, kwc, kwi, kwfm from misure where dataora between '$startTime 00:00:00.000' and '$endTime 00:00:00.000' ) as q1 
                JOIN 
            (select dataora, (Test) as test from temperature where dataora between '$startTime 00:00:00.000' and '$endTime 00:00:00.000' ) as q2 
                ON q1.time=q2.dataora");

 //one week range loads hourly data
} elseif ($range < 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000) {
        if (!$link)     {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());};  
            //echo "hourly data1" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($link,"select 1000*unix_timestamp(q1.time) as time, q1.kwhg, q1.kwhc, q1.kwhi, q1.kwhfm, q2.test from (
SELECT
      (t1.dt) AS time,(case
     when t1.value>t2.value AND t2.value>0
          then abs(t1.value - t2.value)
     when t1.value>t2.value AND t2.value=0
          then t2.value
          else t1.value END)kwhg, 
     (case
     when t1.value1>t2.value1 AND t2.value1>0
          then abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1)
     when t1.value1>t2.value1 AND t2.value1=0
          then t2.value1
     when t1.value1=t2.value1 AND t1.value1>0 
        then abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1)
      else 0 END) kwhc, 
      (case
     when t1.value2>t2.value2 AND t2.value2>0
          then abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2)
     when t1.value2>t2.value2 AND t2.value2=0
          then t2.value2
     when t1.value2=t2.value2 AND t1.value2>0 
        then abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2)
      else 0 END)kwhi,
    (case
     when t1.value3>t2.value3 AND t2.value3>0
          then abs(t1.value3 - t2.value3)
     when t1.value3>t2.value3 AND t2.value3=0
          then t2.value3
     when t1.value3=t2.value3 AND t1.value3>0 
        then abs(t1.value3 - t2.value3)
      else 0 END) kwhfm
    FROM 
        (SELECT (dataora) dt, MAX(kwhg) value, MAX(kwhc) value1, MAX(kwhi) value2, MAX(kwhfm) value3  FROM misure where dataora between '$startTime 00:00:00.000' and '$endTime 00:00:00.000' GROUP BY date(dt),hour(dt)) t1
        JOIN
        (SELECT (dataora) dt, MAX(kwhg) value, MAX(kwhc) value1, MAX(kwhi) value2, MAX(kwhfm) value3  FROM misure where dataora between '$startTime 00:00:00.000' and '$endTime 00:00:00.000' GROUP BY date(dt),hour(dt)) t2
        on t1.dt = t2.dt + interval 1 hour) as q1
JOIN
    (select dataora, AVG(Test) as test from temperature where dataora between '$startTime 00:00:00.000' and '$endTime 00:00:00.000' GROUP BY date(dataora),hour(dataora))  as q2
    ON q1.time=q2.dataora");

// one month range loads hourly data
} elseif ($range < 31 * 24 * 3600 * 1000) {
        if (!$link)     {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());};  
            //echo "hourly data2" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($link,"select 1000*unix_timestamp(q1.time) as time, q1.kwhg, q1.kwhc, q1.kwhi, q1.kwhfm, q2.test from (
SELECT
      (t1.dt) AS time,(case
     when t1.value>t2.value AND t2.value>0
          then abs(t1.value - t2.value)
     when t1.value>t2.value AND t2.value=0
          then t2.value
          else t1.value END)kwhg, 
     (case
     when t1.value1>t2.value1 AND t2.value1>0
          then abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1)
     when t1.value1>t2.value1 AND t2.value1=0
          then t2.value1
     when t1.value1=t2.value1 AND t1.value1>0 
        then abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1)
      else 0 END) kwhc, 
      (case
     when t1.value2>t2.value2 AND t2.value2>0
          then abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2)
     when t1.value2>t2.value2 AND t2.value2=0
          then t2.value2
     when t1.value2=t2.value2 AND t1.value2>0 
        then abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2)
      else 0 END)kwhi,
    (case
     when t1.value3>t2.value3 AND t2.value3>0
          then abs(t1.value3 - t2.value3)
     when t1.value3>t2.value3 AND t2.value3=0
          then t2.value3
     when t1.value3=t2.value3 AND t1.value3>0 
        then abs(t1.value3 - t2.value3)
      else 0 END) kwhfm
    FROM 
        (SELECT (dataora) dt, MAX(kwhg) value, MAX(kwhc) value1, MAX(kwhi) value2, MAX(kwhfm) value3  FROM misure where dataora between '$startTime 00:00:00.000' and '$endTime 00:00:00.000' GROUP BY date(dt),hour(dt)) t1
        JOIN
        (SELECT (dataora) dt, MAX(kwhg) value, MAX(kwhc) value1, MAX(kwhi) value2, MAX(kwhfm) value3  FROM misure where dataora between '$startTime 00:00:00.000' and '$endTime 00:00:00.000' GROUP BY date(dt),hour(dt)) t2
        on t1.dt = t2.dt + interval 1 hour) as q1
JOIN
    (select dataora, AVG(Test) as test from temperature where dataora between '$startTime 00:00:00.000' and '$endTime 00:00:00.000' GROUP BY date(dataora),hour(dataora))  as q2
    ON q1.time=q2.dataora");

// one year range loads daily data
} elseif ($range < 15 * 31 * 24 * 3600 * 1000) {
        if (!$link)     {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());};  
            //echo "daily data2" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($link,"select  1000*unix_timestamp(q1.time) as time, q1.kwhg, q1.kwhc, q1.kwhi, q1.kwhfm, q2.test from (
SELECT
      (t1.dt) AS time,(case
     when t1.value>t2.value AND t2.value>0
          then abs(t1.value - t2.value)
     when t1.value>t2.value AND t2.value=0
          then t2.value
          else t1.value END)kwhg, 
     (case
     when t1.value1>t2.value1 AND t2.value1>0
          then abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1)
     when t1.value1>t2.value1 AND t2.value1=0
          then t2.value1
     when t1.value1=t2.value1 AND t1.value1>0 
        then abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1)
      else 0 END) kwhc, 
      (case
     when t1.value2>t2.value2 AND t2.value2>0
          then abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2)
     when t1.value2>t2.value2 AND t2.value2=0
          then t2.value2
     when t1.value2=t2.value2 AND t1.value2>0 
        then abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2)
      else 0 END)kwhi,
    (case
     when t1.value3>t2.value3 AND t2.value3>0
          then abs(t1.value3 - t2.value3)
     when t1.value3>t2.value3 AND t2.value3=0
          then t2.value3
     when t1.value3=t2.value3 AND t1.value3>0 
        then abs(t1.value3 - t2.value3)
      else 0 END) kwhfm
    FROM 
        (SELECT (dataora) dt, MAX(kwhg) value, MAX(kwhc) value1, MAX(kwhi) value2, MAX(kwhfm) value3  FROM misure where dataora between '$startTime 00:00:00.000' and '$endTime 00:00:00.000' GROUP BY date(dt)) t1
        JOIN
        (SELECT (dataora) dt, MAX(kwhg) value, MAX(kwhc) value1, MAX(kwhi) value2, MAX(kwhfm) value3  FROM misure where dataora between '$startTime 00:00:00.000' and '$endTime 00:00:00.000' GROUP BY date(dt)) t2
        on t1.dt = t2.dt + interval 1 day) as q1
JOIN
    (select dataora, AVG(Test) as test from temperature where dataora between '$startTime 00:00:00.000' and '$endTime 00:00:00.000' GROUP BY date(dataora))  as q2
    ON q1.time=q2.dataora");

// greater range loads monthly data
} else {
        if (!$link)     {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());};
                //echo "monthly data2" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($link,"select 1000*unix_timestamp(q1.time) as time, q1.kwhg, q1.kwhc, q1.kwhi, q1.kwhfm, q2.test from (
SELECT
      (t1.dt) AS time,(case
     when t1.value>t2.value AND t2.value>0
          then abs(t1.value - t2.value)
     when t1.value>t2.value AND t2.value=0
          then t2.value
          else t1.value END)kwhg, 
     (case
     when t1.value1>t2.value1 AND t2.value1>0
          then abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1)
     when t1.value1>t2.value1 AND t2.value1=0
          then t2.value1
     when t1.value1=t2.value1 AND t1.value1>0 
        then abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1)
      else 0 END) kwhc, 
      (case
     when t1.value2>t2.value2 AND t2.value2>0
          then abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2)
     when t1.value2>t2.value2 AND t2.value2=0
          then t2.value2
     when t1.value2=t2.value2 AND t1.value2>0 
        then abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2)
      else 0 END)kwhi,
    (case
     when t1.value3>t2.value3 AND t2.value3>0
          then abs(t1.value3 - t2.value3)
     when t1.value3>t2.value3 AND t2.value3=0
          then t2.value3
     when t1.value3=t2.value3 AND t1.value3>0 
        then abs(t1.value3 - t2.value3)
      else 0 END) kwhfm
    FROM 
        (SELECT (dataora) dt, MAX(kwhg) value, MAX(kwhc) value1, MAX(kwhi) value2, MAX(kwhfm) value3  FROM misure where dataora between '$startTime 00:00:00.000' and '$endTime 00:00:00.000' GROUP BY date(dt),hour(dt)) t1
        JOIN
        (SELECT (dataora) dt, MAX(kwhg) value, MAX(kwhc) value1, MAX(kwhi) value2, MAX(kwhfm) value3  FROM misure where dataora between '$startTime 00:00:00.000' and '$endTime 00:00:00.000' GROUP BY date(dt),hour(dt)) t2
        on t1.dt = t2.dt + interval 1 month) as q1
JOIN
    (select dataora, AVG(Test) as test from temperature where dataora between '$startTime 00:00:00.000' and '$endTime 00:00:00.000' GROUP BY date(dataora),hour(dataora))  as q2
    ON q1.time=q2.dataora");
};
        $rowst = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            extract($row);
            $rowst[] = "[$time,$test,$kwhg,$kwhc,$kwhi,$kwhfm]";
                                                    }
// print it
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
echo "/* console.log(' range = $range, start = $start, end = $end, startTime = $startTime, endTime = $endTime '); */";
echo $callback ."([\n" . join(",\n", $rowst) ."\n]);";

?>
```

i cannot understand why jsfiddle show me the correct charts, but my browser cannot do the same thing with the same code.
Thanks in advance
ps: this is my test page: 79.28.203.203/telegestione/grafico_nuovo.html and this is the chart resulted from my code[image]
and with column series: [image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution appeared to be weird too: i have to invert the e.max and e.min value in ajax request, and everything is ok. But i cannot get the 15 minutes data when i select "day" in range navigator.

```
$.getJSON('grafico_nuovo.php?start='+ Math.round(e.max) +
                        '&end='+ Math.round(e.min) +'&callback=?', function(data)   {
```